# Moving my elements to the right?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm working with HTML and CSS and I want to align the form and the logo more to the right:

[image]

The positions I want are more like this if I do a mockup:
[image]

My HTML is

```
      <!DOCTYPE hml>
                        <html>
                                <head>  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/welcome/static/css/register.css"/>

                                <STYLE TYPE="text/css">



</STYLE> 


                                        <title>{% trans %}Register new distributor{% endtrans %}</title>
                                </head>
                                <body>     <div id="content">
                                <form action="{{action}}" method="post"><img src="/welcome/static/images/reg-reg.gif">

                                               <table><tr><td>

                                                <label>Pers. number </label></td><td><input type="text" name="soc_sec" placeholder="{% trans %}Your social security number{% endtrans %}" />({% trans %}YYMMDDXX{% endtrans %})</td></tr><tr><td>

 <label for="start">Sponsor ID</label></td><td>
                        <input type="text" id="start" name="Log1" size="3" maxlength="3" />
                        <input type="text" name="Log2" size="3" maxlength="3" />
                        <input type="text" name="Log3" size="3" maxlength="3" />
                <input type="text" name="Log4" size="3" maxlength="3" />(<a href="/sponsor-id-info.html">{% trans %}What is a sponsor ID{% endtrans %}?</a>)</td><td></tr><tr><td>
                                                <label>Email</label></td><td> <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="{% trans %}Your email{% endtrans %}" /></td></tr><tr><td>
 <label>{% trans %}First name{% endtrans %}</label></td><td><input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="{% trans %}Your first name{% endtrans %}" /></td></tr><tr><td>
 <label>{% trans %}Last name{% endtrans %}</label></td><td><input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="{% trans %}Your last name{% endtrans %}" /></td></tr><tr>
 <td>
 <label>{% trans %}Address{% endtrans %}</label></td><td><input type="text" name="address" placeholder="{% trans %}Your address{% endtrans %}" /></td></tr><tr><td>
<label>{% trans %}Zip code{% endtrans %}</label></td><td><input type="text" name="zipcode" placeholder="{% trans %}Your zip code{% endtrans %}" /></td></tr><tr><td>
<label>{% trans %}City{% endtrans %}</label></td><td><input type="text" name="city" placeholder="{% trans %}City{% endtrans %}" /></td></tr><tr><td>
<label>{% trans %}Phone{% endtrans %}</label></td><td><input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="{% trans %}Your phone number{% endtrans %}" /></td></tr></table>


                                        <button>{% trans %}Next{% endtrans %}</button>
                                </form><img src="/welcome/static/images/snabbreg002.jpg"></div>
                        </html>
```

And my CSS is

```
BODY {background-image: url(/welcome/static/images/reg-bg.png); background-repeat: repeat-x; }

#content {
  width: 700px ;
  margin-left: auto ;
  margin-right: auto ;
}
```

Could you advice how to align my components more to the right like in the lower picture?

Thank you

### Update

Now I could align the logo to the right, all that is left to be done is moving the form to the right. How do I do it?

[image]

Comment: add float:right to the element you want to make it on right

Comment: thanks for the comment. I could move the logo to the right, now I just want to align the form to the right, but more like centering it.

Comment: also apply float:right to the form and adjust the width of the form, it will be on right then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your css is right, but try to apply it to a div *inside* the content div:

Html:

```
<div id="content">
  <div id="content-container">
    <form ...>
      ...
    </form>
    <img id="image-logo" .../>
  </div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
#content-container {
  width: 700px ;
  margin: 0  auto;
}
#image-logo {
  float: right;
}
```

Also, the image needs a right floating to position as you expect.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I could manage to align the logo to the right. Now I want to move the form to the right but not as much as the logo. I've updated the question with the details.

Comment: @NickRosencrantz, pay attention to my answer, it says to create a div#content-container inside the div#content and apply the css to the div#content-container.

Comment: Many thanks @falsarella I could manage to control the components now with divs.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is probably using float and/or margin.
You can right position your elements with float, `float:right;`.
Also have a look at margin, example : `margin-left:100px;`

```
<img src="/welcome/static/images/snabbreg002.jpg" style="float:right;">
```

Or with css.

```
<img src="/welcome/static/images/snabbreg002.jpg" class="img">
```

css:

```
.img{
float:right;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That was was I needed. I've update the question with the result. Now I also want to move the form a bit to the right, like centering or or something like that. How can it be done?

Answer (score 2):

Add `style="float:right"` to your image.

give the style `margin-left:10px;` for example to your form

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

```
#content {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 600px;
    top: 400px;
}
```

You have to put the right pixels count in.

Answer (score 1):

You may wrap the form in a div and style the div with the appropriate left margin.
You may also try to align the image to the right instead of the left.

Comment: Thank you. I could fix the image. I just need to move the form now. I've update the original question with the updates.

Comment: just style the div with a left margin: in your css `#content {margin-left: 200px;}`

Answer (score 1):

float:right on the element you want to be moved to the right on the same level